# get list of video files into csv from google disk using R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have folder on google disk with video files, and i want get the list of video into csv format

```
url <- "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JidqB3TfHn0Cky8VBXHjbmHu7s0rGLrO?usp=sharing"
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url, temp)
bank <- read.csv(temp)
unlink(temp)
```

output X.csv file  with links like

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aYVn6L7147dDPcOb5CKC3RHh28fS7qix
https://drive.google.com/open?id=18fDVBhfyAHqUffG0GNFGti7549G43bhZ
...
```

How to do it?
now i get error

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

Comment: Check out the googledrive package . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not downloading the files with your code. If you just want the list of files you can use:

```
googledrive::drive_ls(path = "path_to_folder")
```

Also, if you want to download files from Google Drive, you can see the *googledrive::drive_download* function.

Comment: googledrive::drive_ls(path = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WIFQIC23_o1__BPmlRDpnYYwmthH2AP-?usp=sharing") then i get error Error: 'path' does not identify at least one Drive file.

Comment: I was not clear. "path_to_folder" in your case is just "test". You don't need the entire url